# Остановка docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть docker-compose, который запускает несколько сервисов.

Данный образ сбилдил и запустил на ноутбуке(Ubuntu 20) и теперь при каждом включении эти сервисы запускаются и работают.

Как сделать, чтобы они работали только при моем запуске?

PS: пробовал:

```
docker-compose stop
```

И так:

```
docker-compose down
```

Ничего не помогает...

Comment: Как вы определили, что сервисы при в каждом включении запускаются и работают?

Comment: @insolor,  командой **docker ps**  + если по адресу в браузере можно зайти на сервисы

Comment: а вы уверены что вы вызываете `docker-compose down` из правильно папки, с правильным `docker-compose.yml`? само по себе оно не остановит все сервисы

Comment: @Exploding Kitten, спасибо. Действительно, я забыл что делал 2 папки с компосом, и видимо когда-то я собрал и запустил старую и забыл про это, а потом работал с другой папкой. Запустил из старой **docker-compose down** и все - теперь не запускается при включении ноута!